# Why method setViewBinder returns many values?

Tags: android

I've got a problem with setViewBinder.

Can't understund why it reteurns in log not one value, but several.

When in DB no data - returns nothing, when 1 - 2 or 4 values, 3-8/

WHY?

Help, please.

```
 scAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() { 
         public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) { 
             Log.i("mylog", "Let's work!"); 
         return false; 
         } 
  });
```

This is layout with ListView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".Main_year" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_months"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:textSize="50sp" >
    </ListView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/month_icon_active"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:src="@drawable/day_icon"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/list_months"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/list_months"
        android:src="@drawable/year_icon"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is layout, which goes in every stroke in listview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivImg"
        android:text="xyz"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivImg"
        android:text="abc"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean "returns many values"?  It returns `void` (i.e. it doesn't have a return value!)

Comment: When I compile this code I get "Let's work Let's work Let's work Let's work" in LogCat, but not just "Let's work". Why?

Comment: Please show your layout with the list view.

Comment: Do you need image of layout?

Comment: No, the layout.  Are you using wrap_content, which would be a bad thing?

Comment: Simon, thank you for help. The answer below is what i was looking for. Why wrap is bad? What is better to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java) of `SimpleCursorAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final ViewBinder binder = mViewBinder;
    final int count = mTo.length;
    final int[] from = mFrom;
    final int[] to = mTo;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
        if (v != null) {
            boolean bound = false;
            if (binder != null) {
                // ViewBinder is called here!!
                bound = binder.setViewValue(v, cursor, from[i]);
            }

            if (!bound) {
                // code omited...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `ViewBinder` is called once for every view of every row of your `ListView`. A row in your `ListView` contains three views, one `ImageView` and two `TextView`s, if your `Cursor` has two rows then the `ViewBinder` will be called 6 times. That's why you see so many "Let's work!" in Logcat.